# Evaluate the integral $\int \sqrt{x^2-2x-3}dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I'm asked to evaluate this integral: $\int \sqrt{x^2-2x-3} dx$

I don't see any other way to solve this except by trigonometric substitution, which is precisely what I did once I completed the square and got $\sqrt{4-(x-1)^2}$ as the integrand.

I then performed a substitution with $(x-1) = 2\sin(\theta)$.

But all of the answer choices contain some natural logarithms in them. I have no clue how that's possible.

What other methods are there for solving this problem?

Comment: There are other methods to do this integral, but the approach provided in the answer is the most straight forward one (and you should try to understand that approach). The naturals logs will appear when you integrate bunch of trig terms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $x^2 - 2x - 3 = (x-1)^2 - 4 $, thus

$$ \int \sqrt{ (x-1)^2 - 2^2 } dx = \int \sqrt{u^2 - 2^2 } du $$

Let $u = 2 \sec \theta $, then ....

Comment: You didn't complete the square correctly. (-2)/2 = -1, (-1)^2 = 1, add and subtract it and you'll get the reverse of what you have. Edit: nope, I goofed. Idk why I flipped em.

Comment: you didnt complete the square correctly chico

Answer (score 0):

**Another method**

Integrate by parts: setting $t=x-1$, we come down to the integral $\;I=\displaystyle\int\sqrt{t^2-4}\,\mathrm d t$.

Set $u=\sqrt{t^2-4}$, $\mathrm dv=\mathrm dt$, whence 
$\mathrm du=\dfrac{t\,\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^2-4}}, \enspace v=t$, and
\begin{align}
I&=t\sqrt{t^2-4}-\int\dfrac{t^2\,\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^2-4}}=t\sqrt{t^2-4}-\int\dfrac{(t^2-4)\,\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^2-4}}-4\int\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^2-4}} \\
&=t\sqrt{t^2-4}-I-4\operatorname{argch}\Bigl(\frac t2\Bigr)
\end{align}
so that $\; I=\dfrac12t\sqrt{t^2-4}-2\operatorname{argch}\Bigl(\dfrac t2\Bigr)$.